# Matrices with $a_{i1}+a_{i2}+...+a_{in}=0$, for all $i=1,2,..,n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let
\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} \end{pmatrix}
for $m=n$, a matrix where
$$a_{11}+a_{12}+...+a_{1n}=0$$
$$a_{21}+a_{22}+...+a_{2n}=0$$
$$...$$
$$a_{n1}+a_{n2}+...+a_{nn}=0$$
Matrix like this take a particular name? Are they being studied? Or not? I met these matrices while doing some exercises and they intrigued me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, these are matrices with the vector $(1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ in their kernel. I don't think they have a particular name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Theo Bendit commented, this just means that $A \mathbb{1} = 0$; with $\mathbb{1}$ the vector of all ones. These matrices are common in statistics, where each column of $A$ is a sample from a distribution, each row of $A$ represents a feature, and $A \mathbb{1} = 0$ says each feature has mean $0$.

Comment: Thanks. Have they a name? Maybe, "covariance matrices"?

Comment: A covariance matrix is something different; it's a matrix of the form $A^TA$, with $A$ normalized so that $A \mathbb{1} = 0$.

Comment: Ok; instead, in statistics, have a particular name the matrices of your post?

Comment: I think a matrix with $A \mathbb{1} = 0$ is sometimes called a mean centered matrix.